# Macbook Pro Retina and Dell u3011 video driver problem

Tags: display, macbook-pro

i have a macbook pro retina with OS X 10.8.4 (12E55) , and i'm connecting it to a dell u3011 monitor using a mini-display to displayport cable , it was working great until today whenever i connect the cable my monitor goes to energy save mode , i thought this was a cable problem so i bought a new one and the problem still remains , i connected to the monitor using HDMI and its working fine , is it a video driver problem?

Comment: are you on battery power ?

Comment: no , not on battery power

Comment: sorry for been late :) so how did you tell your MBP what to do when you plug in external monitor, so it does not run off the build in one !

Comment: it works out of the box when i connect the cable , no need for configurations

Comment: Well,, check your energy save settings n the system preferences anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Incredibly late answer, but I had the same issue and what worked for me was to [reset the NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379).